# create 2D array and pointer to &array-1

Tags: c, embedded

For a display driver in an arm project, I want to access the buffer as 2D array to access it like this:

```
e.g. display_buffer[2][113]=0xff;
```

To write the buffer out to the display via I2C I want to write the whole buffer out, but need to prepend it with 0x40.

```
io_write(I2C_0_io, (uint8_t *)buf, 513); //where buf should be 0x40,content, of, display_buffer,...
```

Is there a way to declare `display_buffer[4][128]` so that it has one byte before it and a pointer that points to it?

I tried

```
uint8_t *_display_buffer = (uint8_t*)513;
uint8_t *display_buffer[4][128]=_display_buffer+1;
```

but of course the compiler thought that this was not a good idea ('invalid initializer')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `_display_buffer` as an array large enough to hold your 2D array plus 1 byte, and `display_buffer` as a pointer to an array (which you can index as a 2D array) instead of a 2D array:

```
uint8_t _display_buffer[513] = { 0x40 };
uint8_t (*display_buffer)[128]=(uint8_t (*)[128])(_display_buffer+1);
```

Comment: Like this I get a pointer that I can use like an array and I can assign a value into the array like this: `*display_buffer[3][121]=0x23`. This is ok and I will use it - I still wonder if there is a way to use an array...

Comment: @Johanness The syntax is actually `display_buffer[3][121]=0x23` with this definition.

Comment: That gives me an 'error: assignment to expression with array type'

Comment: @Johanness Then you copied the definitions incorrectly.  Check again.

Comment: I made an adjustment for the 2D `uint8_t (*display_buffer)[4][128]=(uint8_t (*)[4][128])(_display_buffer+1);` thats probably the problem. But I cannnot figure aout why one should work and the other shouldn't.

Comment: @Johanness What you have is a pointer to a 2D array, so it requires an extra level of dereferencing.  My answer has a pointer to a 1D array, which can be treated as a 2D array.

Comment: So I declare a array[128] and use it as array[4][128]... I will have a lot to learn. But this works flawless. Thank you .